# When using UsageStats how to set OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS transparently

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I try to use usage stats but after retrieving successfully the list of installed apps I try to query the usage stats but I get a 0 value.

After looking in StackOverflow I see that there is an extra permission on top of PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS: OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS

When I check this permission I don't have it.

Why isn't PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS sufficient?

Does it exist a way to set this permission programmatically?

Otherwise, I don't like the idea of re-directing the user to Settings: isn't it a way to prompt the user in the UI to allow this permission?

Here is an extract of my code:

manifest

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

java code:

```
void getInstalledApp() {
    List<String> installedApps = getInstalledAppList();
    if(!checkForPermission())
        Log.i("PERM", "false");
    List<UsageStats> usageStats =
            usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY,
                    getStartTime(), System.currentTimeMillis());

    List<UsageStats> stats = new ArrayList<>();
}

private List<String> getInstalledAppList(){
    List<ApplicationInfo> infos = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flags);
    List<String> installedApps = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : infos){
        installedApps.add(info.packageName);
    }
    return installedApps;
}

private long getStartTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

private boolean checkForPermission() {
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, myUid(), activity.getPackageName());
    return mode == MODE_ALLOWED;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this method for asking permission from user if not granted:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void checkForUsageStatsPermission() {
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = 0;
    if (appOps != null) {
        mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, android.os.Process.myUid(), getActivity().getPackageName());
    }
    if (mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I implemented thinking that there are no other choices but I consider this as a lack of consistency for permissions management.

Comment: Works. I just needed to remove the first line and add some imports.